# JPA mapping MAP<Entity, Embedable>

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I've 2 classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "es_item")
public class Item {
    @Id
    @Column(name= "inventory_item_id")
    public int getInventoryItemID(){
        return inventoryItemID;
    }

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = ItemConversionAttributes.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name="component_item_id", referencedColumnName = "inventory_item_id")
    @CollectionTable(name="es_bom_levels", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "inventory_item_id"))
    public Map<Item, ItemConversionAttributes> getConversionAttributes(){ return conversionAttributes; }
}

@Embeddable
public class ItemConversionAttributes {
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity=Item.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="component_item_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    @NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    public Item getComponentItem(){ return componentItem; }
}
```

The structure of db is
es_item has columns: inventory_item_id is key, some orther columns.
es_bom_level has columns: inventory_item_id, component_item_id. with component_item_id is fk to es_item.
the my mapping does not work. I see the error
`Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: vmjboss7] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:889)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:162)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.start(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:85)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        ... 3 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for collection: com.biz.model.Item.conversionAttributes column: component_item_id
        at org.hibernate.mapping.Collection.checkColumnDuplication(Collection.java:341)
        at org.hibernate.mapping.Collection.checkColumnDuplication(Collection.java:364)
        at org.hibernate.mapping.Collection.validate(Collection.java:321)
        at org.hibernate.mapping.IndexedCollection.validate(IndexedCollection.java:89)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1298)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1742)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:84)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:904)` 
Please help me.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you post the error log

Comment: Please define "does not work".

Comment: es_item has columns: inventory_item_id is key, some orther columns. es_bom_level has columns: inventory_item_id, component_item_id. with component_item_id is fk to es_item.  Is component_item_id the fk or is it inventory_item_id? because you have mentioned that inventory_item_id is present in both the tables

Comment: This is many kind of circle relationship. from es_item we can search many row in es_bom_level by inventory_item_id. Then from es_bom_level, we can use com_ponent_item_id to search many row in es_item. The business logic is: we have item, and we can know related items in this Build Of Material.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay in response as I was stuck with other issues :-(

Please try the below code:-

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "es_item")
public class Item {
    @Id
    @Column(name= "inventory_item_id")
    private int inventoryItemID;    

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)   
    @CollectionTable(name="es_bom_levels", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "component_item_id"))
    @MapKeyJoinColumn()
    public Map<Item, ItemConversionAttributes> conversionAttributes;

    ......
    // getters and setters
}

@Embeddable
class ItemConversionAttributes {

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity=Item.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="inventory_item_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    @NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    private Item componentItem;

    ..........
    // getters and setters
}
```

A catch here is that this setup creates an additional column and constraint in you es_bom_levels table which is as expected (my guess) after I went through the below blog

[mappingembeddable](http://hwellmann.blogspot.in/2010/07/jpa-20-mapping-map.html)

Comment: @duykaka The above solution works fine for me. Would it be possible for you to share the solution which you tried this time and also the test case along with some dummy data in the tables you mentioned.

Comment: Hi Anand, I review your mapping, I think it has some missing key point. From Item I use inventory_item_id map to inventory_item_id in es_bom_level, then I get multiple rows. Foreach row I got component_item_id, I use it to map to inventory_item_id in es_item to get the key of Map. Mapping should be `@CollectionTable(name="es_bom_levels", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "inventory_item_id")) and @JoinColumn(name="component_item_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)`